# Getting / setting file owner in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a requirement to read and display the owner of a file (for audit purposes), and potentially changing it as well (this is secondary requirement). Are there any nice C# wrappers?

After a quick google, I found only [the WMI solution](http://web.archive.org/web/20061116233324/http://www.softinsight.com/bnoyes/PermaLink.aspx?guid=8edc9d4c-0f2c-4006-8186-a3697ebc7476) and a suggestion to PInvoke GetSecurityInfo

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241718/taking-ownership-of-files-with-broken-permissions and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368825/taking-ownership-of-a-file-or-folder

Answer (score 50, accepted):

No need to P/Invoke. [System.IO.File.GetAccessControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getaccesscontrol.aspx) will return a [FileSecurity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.filesecurity_members.aspx) object, which has a [GetOwner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.objectsecurity.getowner.aspx) method.

Edit: Reading the owner is pretty simple, though it's a bit of a cumbersome API:

```
const string FILE = @"C:\test.txt";

var fs = File.GetAccessControl(FILE);

var sid = fs.GetOwner(typeof(SecurityIdentifier));
Console.WriteLine(sid); // SID

var ntAccount = sid.Translate(typeof(NTAccount));
Console.WriteLine(ntAccount); // DOMAIN\username
```

Setting the owner requires a call to SetAccessControl to save the changes. Also, you're still bound by the Windows rules of ownership - you can't assign ownership to another account. You can give take ownership perms, and they have to take ownership.

```
var ntAccount = new NTAccount("DOMAIN", "username");
fs.SetOwner(ntAccount);

try {
   File.SetAccessControl(FILE, fs);
} catch (InvalidOperationException ex) {
   Console.WriteLine("You cannot assign ownership to that user." +
    "Either you don't have TakeOwnership permissions, or it is not your user account."
   );
   throw;
}
```

Comment: When I try this it just returns "\\BUILTIN\Administrators" as the owner. Even though in explorer it shows the owner as my login on the correct domain etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(@"C:\test.txt");
string user = fi.GetAccessControl().GetOwner(typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)).ToString();
```