# C# get file owner in Windows

Tags: c#, file, owner

I want to get the owner of a file using the code below

```
File.GetAccessControl(filename).GetOwner(typeof(SecurityIdentifier)).Translate(typeof(NTAccount))
```

However, it gives me BUILTIN\Administrators as the owner, but I can see in the file explorer the owner is Domain\MyUserName.

Why this happens and how can fix it?

**Edit:** [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370146/how-can-i-find-out-who-created-a-file-in-windows-using-net) explain what happen. It is to do with the files created by users in the Administrator Group and how Windows handle the owner of these files.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370146/how-can-i-find-out-who-created-a-file-in-windows-using-net

Comment: Is it still incorrect  if you do `NTAccount ntAccount = File.GetAccessControl(filename).GetOwner(typeof(SecurityIdentifier)).Translate(typeof(NTAccount)) as NTAccount;`

Comment: @3dd still gives me Administrators, but the link posted by  Chandrashekar Jupalli explains why. It is to do with my Admin privilege and how windows handles file created by Adminstors

Comment: @Helic - I tried your code right now, and it always returns the correct `NTAccount` for all files I tried (locally and on network drives). Even though I'm in the admin group...

Comment: @Herdo, that is strange, let me try it with a guest account

Comment: @Helic Sure. Maybe there's a different handling for the "local administrator group" and the "ADS administrator group". Also there might be differences in OS and ADS settings, that cause this issue for you. Obviously in my company network, my PC running Windows 8.0, it works correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get the actual owner of a file by this... not sure if this is what you need or not.
`System.IO.FileInfo Fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(@"path2file");`

`MessageBox.Show(Fi.GetAccessControl().GetOwner(typeof(System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier)).Translate(typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)).ToString());`