# ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED setting file owner

Tags: c++, winapi, ntfs, file-security

I am trying to set the owner of a file to another user programmatically in C++.

I have definitely enabled the `SeRestorePrivilege` for my process. I can confirm this using Process Explorer. I start the process, it is disabled, I run my code to enable it, ProcExp reports it as enabled, I go just up to the point where the owner is to be set, and it is still enabled (i.e. I am not accidentally disabling it).

What other caused can there be for this access is denied message? What have I not considered?

```
std::wstring fileSystemObject = L"C:\test.txt";
*status_code = SetNamedSecurityInfo((wchar_t*)fileSystemObject.c_str(), SE_FILE_OBJECT, OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION, pSID, NULL, NULL, NULL);
if (*status_code == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    Log(L"Successfully set owner for " + fileSystemObject);
    return true;
}
else
{
    Log(L"Failed to set owner for " + fileSystemObject + L". Error code: ", *status_code);
    return false;
}
```

Thank you.

**EDIT:** Thank you very much for your continued assistance. It is greatly appreciated.

I used your code for all of the following tests. Basically, I am also getting Access Denied messages from your code, however, I have tracked it down a little more.

Firstly, "C:\test.txt" was not my real code, and unfortunately the missing backslash is not the cause of my problem. Thank you for your keen eyes though :)

Also, I am running an administrator account with UAC disabled, and my program has requireAdministrator set in the manifest.

However, I have noticed that both my code and yours work for simple files. After much testing, I have discovered that I only get AccessDenied messages in the following scenarios:

1: I am not the owner, and the "Take Ownership" permissions is set to Deny for e.g. Everyone.

2: I am the owner, and the "Take Ownership" permissions is set to Deny for e.g. Everyone. Curiously, in this second instance, despite the failure code, the ownership change does actually occur.

I don't see why this is happening. I, and you, have set SE_RESTORE_NAME in the process token. I should be allowed to arbitrarily set the owner SID. But it seems that I can't.

It seems that any Deny on TakeOwnership DACLs overrides my ability to take ownership. However, I can't change permissions until I can take ownership! *sigh*.

I might try setting SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege as you initially recommended, taking ownership to myself, changing permissions, setting ownership externally. What a pain. And I am not even very confident it will work.

I also found this: http://us.generation-nt.com/setnamedsecurityinfo-failing-rc-1307-help-59729462.html

He seems to be in a similar situation (I get 1307 if I don't set up the process token properly). But CreatePrivateObjectSecurityEx takes a whole lot more setting up.

Hmmmm. Thanks for your time.

Comment: `SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege`? http://stackoverflow.com/a/5454795/868014

Comment: Thank you for your help. My understanding (which may be flawed - my code doesn't work!) is that SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege allows me to set the owner to myself (and then I suppose to another user). However, I thought that SeRestorePrivilege should allow me to set it directly to another user without that extra step.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/08/18/453054.aspx

Comment: I just made [a quick test](http://www.alax.info/trac/public/browser/trunk/Utilities/Miscellaneous/SetFileOwner/SetFileOwner.cpp) and it worked out well for me. I wonder if it is `C:\t` in your real code, and not `C:\\t`? I thought you might also have privilege elevation for it to succeed.

Comment: I have updated my question because it would be too long for a  comment.

Comment: Found someone else with the same problem: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ta/winserverpowershell/thread/b0fb57e2-af05-440a-9759-35ed93004017 http://www.networksteve.com/forum/topic.php/Strange_access_denial_with_quite_extended_rights/?TopicId=5780&Posts=9 No solution, unfortunately.

Comment: Well, DACL denying taking ownership might be a problem. However, even in this case enabling additionally `SE_TAKE_OWNERSHIP_NAME` seems to be a solution. It thought that it might take to take ownership onto self, then temporarily removing DACL, but nope just an extra privilege worked out: [updated code](http://www.alax.info/trac/public/browser/trunk/Utilities/Miscellaneous/SetFileOwner/SetFileOwner.cpp#L36).

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Your fix has worked perfectly. If you create an answer of this, I will happily mark it as such. Thank you so, so much again!!

Comment: Agh! I spoke too soon. Now I keep on getting ERROR_INVALID_OWNER. Give me a bit of time to investigate. I'll try lots of things, and come back if I can't solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that security subsystem and model are defending the object from unreasonable ownership changes, and even having administrator permissions one needs to correctly overcome the obstacles.

There are two privileges involved in taking ownership of a file: `SE_TAKE_OWNERSHIP_NAME` and `SE_RESTORE_NAME`. The former allows taking someone's object and the latter allows setting owner who is not the setter himself.

It might look like `SE_RESTORE_NAME` is a more powerful privilege and is sufficient for the task, however it appears that it is not. Yes it allows to set someone's ownership, [as MSDN states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379579%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> If the caller does not have the SeRestorePrivilege constant (see
>   Privilege Constants), this SID must be contained in the caller's
>   token, and must have the SE_GROUP_OWNER permission enabled. The
>   SecurityInfo parameter must include the OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION
>   flag. To set the owner, the caller must have WRITE_OWNER access to the
>   object or have the SE_TAKE_OWNERSHIP_NAME privilege enabled.

However it does not let you overcome DACL item that explicitly prevents from ownership change. In this case you need that other privilege as well (that is, you need to enable both), which enables you to take ownership from someone before you decide whom you are going to give it then to.

I am copying the link to C++/ATL source code from comment above: [SetFileOwner.cpp](http://www.alax.info/trac/public/browser/trunk/Utilities/Miscellaneous/SetFileOwner/SetFileOwner.cpp#L36). When permissions/DACL has a Deny item, an exception takes place and enabling second privilege resolves the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, once again. All is working well now. I am sorry I took so long to respond. It has been extremely hectic. My thanks again :)