# What user permissions do I need to reset FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE attribute on a file?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, file-permissions, ntfs

I'm using [SetFileAttributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365535(v=vs.85).aspx) API to reset `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE` attribute on files. My app that I need it for acts as a backup software. Here's how I do it:

```
DWORD dwAtt = ::GetFileAttributes(strSrcFilePath);
if(dwAtt != INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES)
{
    if(!::SetFileAttributes(strSrcFilePath, dwAtt & ~FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE))
    {
        //Error
        int error = ::GetLastError();
    }
}
```

The user account that my process runs under belongs to the `Backup Operators` group:

[image]

which according to [this document](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windowsnt/4/server/proddocs/en-us/concept/xcp02.mspx?mfr=true) should give my process access to modify files regardless of their permissions.

But when I run the code above, `SetFileAttributes` fails with `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`.

Am I missing something?

Do I need to give my process write-access to the file just to reset its `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE` attribute?

Comment: Can you log into the PC with that account and manually set file attributes as a test?

Comment: Just having backup privileges isn't enough.  The program has to enable them (using AdjustTokenPrivileges) and in some cases (e.g., CreateFile) also has to use a special flag as described in the documentation of the relevant API function.

Comment: @RandySchuman: No, I can't set them through Windows Explorer if I log in under my `BackupUser` account.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Yes. Fair enough. Can you elaborate on which privilege do I need to enable using `AdjustTokenPrivileges` though? Also how does `CreateFile` fit into it? I'm not creating those files that I'm backing up. I'm simply copying them and then need to reset the `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE` on them.

Comment: CreateFile was just an example.  For SetFileAttributes, all you have to do is to enable the relevant privilege(s).  Since you're both reading and setting the flags, I think you'll need both SE_RESTORE_PRIVILEGE and SE_BACKUP_PRIVILEGE.

Comment: @c00000fd  This may be what you need. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338711/error-access-denied-setting-file-owner/12341165#12341165

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Just tried to enable both `SE_RESTORE_NAME` and `SE_BACKUP_NAME` in my process running under my `BackupUser` account and `AdjustTokenPrivileges` failed on both with `ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED`.

Comment: @RandySchuman: No. If I take ownership of the files that my app is trying to back up it will seriously mess up the system. Plus, I have to run it as an admin to do it anyway. My `BackupUser` is just a standard user account.

Comment: If a user has backup privileges, UAC kicks in.  You'll need to run your program elevated.  I *think* you can do this using the non-admin account and just get backup privileges and not everything else, though I'm not sure; UAC gets a bit confused in this scenario if I remember rightly.  Best solution is to just make the user an administrator.  Having backup privileges is equivalent to being an administrator anyway.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Yep, you got it. Appreciate your help! I technically need only `SE_RESTORE_NAME` privilege and to run my process elevated. And it does the job. Why did you also mention `SE_BACKUP_NAME` though?

Comment: I think that you will need `SE_BACKUP_NAME` as well if you have to deal with the case where you don't have read permission either to the file or to its parent directory.  (Theoretically, backup privilege lets you bypass the rules that would stop you from reading something, and restore privilege lets you bypass the rules that would stop you from writing something.  But in practice they might not be implemented that way, I've never checked.)

Comment: @c00000fd  Ok, wasn't sure, just thought the link might help. Glad you got it working.