# Find out File Owner/Creator in C#

Tags: c#, file-ownership

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting / setting file owner in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153087/getting-setting-file-owner-in-c)

I searched the Internet but didn't found out how to get the File Creator/Owner
In the FileInfo Class are only other Attributes like lastAccessTime, Size, but not the Owner/Creator.

Does somebody know the answer?

Comment: that helped a lot! thx George!

Comment: Don't forget to upvote the answer on the other question if it helped you! ;)

Comment: can't upvote, I need a Reputation of 15.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```cs
string user = System.IO.File.GetAccessControl(path).GetOwner(typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)).ToString();
```

**[EDIT]** for newer .net versions, you will need to install [System.IO.FileSystem.AccessControl](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IO.FileSystem.AccessControl/)

Comment: That's what I was searching for, thanks!

Comment: Any way to do this in .NET 6?