# How to get File Author Name in .NET?

Tags: c#

I have a folder on a shared server that folder has many files. I need to retrieve information about the Files Author Name (The name of the user who created or last updated he file in the folder).

I tried some code samples available on web but it gives the domain and the computer name but not the actual user/author name.

I tried below:

```
const string FILE = @"C:\temp\temp.txt";
var fs = File.GetAccessControl(FILE);
var sid = fs.GetOwner(typeof(SecurityIdentifier));
Console.WriteLine(sid); // SID
var ntAccount = sid.Translate(typeof(NTAccount));
var STRING = ntAccount.Value;
Console.Write(ntAccount); // DOMAIN\username
```

but it only gives *DOMAIN\computer* name.

Comment: In order to track writes to files on a share, you'll need to enable [Detailed File Share auditing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/audit-detailed-file-share) on the machine hosting the share and then consume the resulting event log entries.

Comment: Does this link help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/7445261/880990