# How to write name of the file's owner to the file using c#?

Tags: c#

Below is the code how to get the name of the file's owner:

```
using System.Security.AccessControl;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.IO;

//...

FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(@"1.txt");
FileSecurity fileSecurity = fileInfo.GetAccessControl();
IdentityReference identityReference = fileSecurity.GetOwner(typeof(NTAccount));
MessageBox.Show(identityReference.Value);
```

Is it possible to write this data to the file using c#?

Comment: you want to write this data as plain text at the end of file?

Comment: @teovankot No, I want to write it to the window "Properties" of the file

Comment: Maby this will help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/153146/1849444

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/153146/1849444)

```
File.Copy(@"1.txt", @"2.txt", true);
string userName = System.IO.File.GetAccessControl(@"1.txt").GetOwner(typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)).ToString();
var fs = File.GetAccessControl(@"2.txt");
var ntAccount = new NTAccount("DOMAIN", userName);
fs.SetOWner(ntAccount);

try {
   File.SetAccessControl(@"2.txt", fs);
} catch (InvalidOperationException ex) {
   Console.WriteLine("You cannot assign ownership to that user." +
    "Either you don't have TakeOwnership permissions, or it is not your user account."
   );
   throw;
}
```