# C# - setting / getting owner of file on other lan pc

Tags: c#, owner, file-ownership

I have 4 computers connected in LAN network. I made some program for file managing. My problem is that i can't get or set owner of, when i access to some file in other pc. I searched on the internet for answers, but nothing solves my problem. Is is possible to get or set owner of file on other pc?

**I tried this:**

```
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog f = new OpenFileDialog();
        f.ShowDialog();
        path = f.FileName;
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     FileSecurity fileS = File.GetAccessControl(path);
            SecurityIdentifier secId = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User;
        fileS.SetOwner(secId);
        fileS.SetAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(secId, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));
        string getOwner = File.GetAccessControl(filepath).GetOwner(typeof(NTAccount)).ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(getOwner);
    }
```

Comment: First try it via Windows explorer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting / setting file owner in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153087/getting-setting-file-owner-in-c-sharp)