# php_posix.dll php extension in windows install?

Tags: php, windows, php-extension

Getting error

```
$cpid = posix_getpid();
```

Error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function posix_getpid() in D:\xampp\htdocs\kill_script\kill.php:4 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\kill_script\kill.php on line 4
```

i need to setup posix in xammp  or any other possible way
https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.posix.php

official docs has not installation steps for winsows platform

Comment: `POSIX functions are enabled by default. You can disable POSIX-like functions with --disable-posix.`

Comment: @MarkusZeller, "Note: This extension is not available on Windows platforms."

Comment: @MarkusZeller default avalible in windows platform in xampp ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41328157/how-to-install-posix-in-windows

Comment: It is working with PHP 8.1 under WSL2 in Windows 11. I've just successfully tested.