# Powerpoint Add-In Application in c# and need to access presentation owner details

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, powerpoint, onedrive

I have to write an Powerpoint Add-In Application in c# that can connect to OneDrive and then uploads file and retrieve files from Onedrive and also I need to get presentation owner details and Sharing details(Other Users permissions, Can edit or Read Only).I have checked system environment variables and I couldn't find anything on my machine. How can I do this programmatically? I have searched online, but I couldn't find anything.
Please help me how to solve this type of requirement..?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the OpenFileDialog and SaveFileDialog to read/write your Powerpoint Files

```
using (OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
{
    openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "OneDrive";
    openFileDialog.Filter = "pptx files (*.pptx)|*.pptx|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    openFileDialog.FilterIndex = 2;
    openFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;

    if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
       //Read the contents of the file into a stream
       var fileStream = openFileDialog.OpenFile();
       // Do your stuff   
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You.I also need presentation owner details and Sharing details(Other Users permissions, Can edit or Read Only).How can i get this data?

Comment: FileInfo might help.

Comment: I couldn't find presentation owner details and user permission

Comment: You could simply google it yourself,  ;)   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153087/getting-setting-file-owner-in-c-sharp